# How do i create a .p12 (or .jks) file from aws Export certificate?

Tags: rest, ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate, aws-certificate-manager

I need a certificate for my server (rest api / https)

In AWS Certificate manager i did create a private CA, after that a private certificate and made an export of it.

The export gave me 3 files

- Certificate body
- Certificate chain
- Certificate private key

these are pem files

i did try to create a p12 or jks file with openssl but they didnt work, the app kind of crashes with
`javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown`

i get this ^^ with `openssl pkcs12 -export -inkey private_key.pem -in all.pem -name test -out server.p12`

when i try a get endpoint in browser, i get a response but the browser says "certificate is not trusted"

i am not sure if i am creating the p12 file in a wrong way or if there is am issue with my steps before with aws

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that you private CA is trusted in your endpoint browser, if not, you have to import it to trusted issuer list(trusted CA) in your browser certificate manager.

Use -certfile parameter to openssl to include your CA:

```
     openssl pkcs12 -export -inkey private_key.pem -in all.pem -certfile yourca.pem -name test -out server.p12
```

Without this parameter, server.p12 may contain just one certificate and private key.
Check your server.p12:

```
     openssl pkcs12 -in server.p12
```

Make sure that your CA included now.

Comment: thx that may work, but i did found a different approach in the mean time.

Comment: .. what approach.

on the answer, might wanna explain what individual keys are referring to